# How to use mage-ci tool to build matrix for CI?

Tags: magento-1.9, ecomdev-phpunit

I was looking for a better way to install and test Magento modules and I found here an entry point: [Test magento module using mage-ci](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53132/how-to-test-magento-module-without-magento-core/53155#53155)

I need further information on:

- How to build such Matrix for CI as used by EcomDev Team?
- How to use the build script mentioned in the link above?

I could comment the answer of *Ivan Chepurnyi* but I think that need more details in a dedicated answer.